# R stacked bar plot with continuous scale

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked bar plot to indicate when requests were made for resources on website. I would like to use a gradient legend to describe when the requests were made. How can I create a gradient legend, and would that be the right way to visualize this time domain data?

```
> head(livePostHit)
                               path       date hits
1     /2017/06/27/goog-fit-cal.html 2018/04/01    1
2  /2015/05/24/sqlite-tutorial.html 2018/04/01    1
3        /2016/11/07/coin-freq.html 2018/04/01    1
4     /2017/03/30/alpine-linux.html 2018/04/01    2
5 /2018/03/09/querySelectorAll.html 2018/04/01    1
6     /2017/11/24/fedora-27-rv.html 2018/04/01    1

> ggplot(livePostHit, aes(x = path, y = hits, fill = date)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(angle=75, hjust = 1),
        legend.position = 'none')
```

I turned off the legend because there were too many groups for it to render correctly, but I would like to create like a gradient for the highest to the lowest.

[image: Graph]

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic on [stats.SE].

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to make date an actual date type rather than a factor.

```
livePostHit$date <- as.Date(livePostHit$date)
```